# Matplotlib -- how to retreive polygons colors from choropleth map

Tags: python, matplotlib, geopandas

I made the choropleth map using GeoPandas and Matplotlib. I want to add value labels to each polygon of the map in a way that font label color must be a contrast to polygon fill color (white on a darker color and black on a lighter).

Thus, I need to know every polygon's fill color. I found the solution (see minimal working example code below).

But I suppose that a more simple and clear solution exists, so I post this question with the hope to find it with community help.

```python
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import islice, pairwise
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

def contrast_color(color):
    d = 0
    r, g, b = (round(x*255, 0) for x in color[:3])     
    luminance = 1 - (0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b) / 255
    d = 0 if luminance < 0.5 else 255
    return (d, d, d)

def get_colors(ax):
    # get childrens 
    # to obtain a PatchCollection
    _ = ax.axes.get_children()
    collection = _[0]  # suppose it is first element
    if not isinstance(collection, PatchCollection):
        raise TypeError("This is not Collection")
    # get information about polygons fill colors
    # .get_facecolors() returns ALL colors for ALL polygons
    # that belongs to one multipolygon
    # e. g. if we have two multipolygons, 
    # and the first consists of two polygons 
    # and second consists of one polygon
    # we obtain THREE colors
    poly_colors = collection.get_facecolors()
    return poly_colors.tolist()

gpd.read_file("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ap-Codkelden/72f988e2bcc90ea3c6c9d6d989d8eb3b/raw/c91927bdb6b199c4dd6df6759200a5a1e4b820f0/obl_sample.geojson")
dfm['coords'] = [x[0] for x in dfm['geometry'].apply(lambda x: x.representative_point().coords[:])]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10, 6))
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_title('Title', fontdict={'fontsize': '12', 'fontweight' : '3'})
dfm.plot(
    ax=ax,
    column='Average', cmap='Blues_r',
    linewidth=0.5, edgecolor='k',
    scheme='FisherJenks', k=2,
    legend=True
)

out = []  # empty container for colors
# count polygons for every multipolygon
# since it can contains more than one
poly_count = dfm.geometry.apply(lambda x: len(x.geoms)).to_list()
poly_colors = get_colors(ax)
# we need split the polygon's colors list into sublists, 
# where every sublist will contain all colors for 
# every polygon that belongs to one multipolygon
slices = [(0, poly_count[0])] + [x for x in pairwise(np.cumsum(poly_count))]
# splitting
for s in slices:
    out.append(
        set(tuple(x) for x in islice(poly_colors, *s)),)
# remove transparensy info
out = [next(iter(x))[:3] for x in out]
dfm['color'] = [tuple([y/255 for y in x]) for x in map(contrast_color, out)]

for idx, row in dfm.iterrows():
    plt.annotate(
        f"{row['reg_en']}\n{row['Average']:.2f}",
        xy=row['coords'], horizontalalignment='center',
        color=row['color'], size=9)
```

Desired labels are:

[image]

Comment: The essence of this question is to make all annotation texts readable everywhere on the map, right? If so, cartographic techniques can be used. For example, draw texts in 2 layers , thicker white texts on lower layer, and normal black texts on upper layer. Use zorder to arrange layers, higher is on top of lower values.

Comment: @swatchai Yes, you're right -- the essence is in text visibility. Thank you for your suggested solution, I didn't think about the cartographic approach at all. But along with that purely applied interest still remain: is achievable to know a polygon's color by some simplified technique?

Comment: Here are some examples worth considering https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/advanced/patheffects_guide.html